# How to deal with baseboard heating causing problems with a headboard?

Tags: walls, baseboard, bedroom

I've got baseboard heating along every wall in the master bedroom.

The bed I bought has a headboard that's tenuously bolted to a frame which doesn't exactly match. On top of that, the baseboard heating makes it such that the headboard is not pressed flat against the wall and whenever a head touches the headboard it's putting pressure on the headboard that makes it start to angle back towards the wall.

This makes it creaky and over time will undoubtably cause the headboard to either snap or come loose from the frame.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach some spacer blocks to the backside of the headboard or the wall  that match the thickness or distance from the headboard  to the wall.  You could use raw wood or wood covered with a matching fabric,  you could build a nook or shelf space to fill that space for storage.  You could reinforce the headboard to the bed frame  with beefy hardware and or gusset braces  so that it will withstand the flexing.

Comment: Yea, I think I'm going to have to stick some wood behind it. Making things more complicated is that the baseboard heater is kind of rounded, so wood sitting on top may not do it, but we'll see. This isn't going to be that easy for me, but I imagine this is what I'll try. Let me leave the question open for a while longer and if there's no better answer I will mark this as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Hack-R Shouldn't be a need to have a piece going all the way to the heater. Just duct tape a couple small pieces on the back of the headboard near the top edge on both sides.